# Database Mail in Sql Server 2008 not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-mail

I am using Database Mail feature of SQL Server 2008 for the first time to send mail.

I followed the steps in [Example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/)

All seems good. Send status in

```
SELECT * FROM sysmail_allitems
```

is sent.

But the recipient hasn't received any mail..

What could be the issue?

Comment: The status from Database Mail just means SQL Server sent it to your SMTP server that is configured. Have you verified that the SMTP server received the request and forwarded it successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a role called DatabaseMailUserRole in SqlServer your user must have access to it to send the mail through Database Mail in Sql Server

To see which users have access:
EXEC msdb.sys.sp_helprolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole';

To add user to this required role:
EXEC msdb.sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'DatabaseMailUserRole'
,@membername = 'userName';

Then execute the command to send mail.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one of the following:
1. settings are incorrect.
2. anti virus or a firewall are blocking your mail.

Comment: This is not really an answer, rather a comment.